# Prove $n\log n\neq O(g(n))$ where $g(n)$ alternates between $\log^*n$ and $n!$

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

I have to prove that $f(n) \neq O(g(n))$, where $f(n) = n\log n$ and $g(n)$ is $\log^*n$ if $n$ is odd and $n!$ if even.

So my thought is to say that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ and then with the definition prove that this is wrong, but i am struggling. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mean $f(n) \neq O(g(n))$?

Comment: Yes, exactly thank you

Comment: I am not sure if this is the way to go, but maybe someone with higher knowledge can give me a double check: Assume $f(n) = O(g(n))$. Then: \begin{equation*} g(n) = \Omega (f(n)) \Rightarrow f(n) = o(g(n)) \Leftrightarrow \lim_n \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 0. \end{equation*} Can you prove this is a contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

There is no constant such that $n\log n<c\log n$ for  all odd $n$. (Obviously, there is no constant such that $n<c$ for  all odd $n$).

Comment: It is not logn, it is log*n

Comment: $\log^*(n) \leqslant \log n$, so the argument still holds.

Comment: Yes I didn’t assume that you are wrong. It’s was my fault

Comment: @gianluigi: see Nathaniel's comment. $log^*$ grows even slower.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest formal approach to question, because, of course, inequalities are important, but also are important conditions on variables in this inequalities.

To prove directly, that some function is not in some big-$O$, you need negation of definition $f(n)\in O(g(n)),n\to\infty$:

formal defintion is
$$\exists c >0, \exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n>n_0, f(n)\leqslant c\cdot g(n) $$
so, negation, $f(n)\notin O(g(n)),n\to\infty$, will be

$$\forall c >0, \forall n_0\in\mathbb{N}, \exists n>n_0, f(n)>c\cdot g(n) $$
In definition $n$ is **variable** and $c,n_0$ are **constants** which we want to find.

In negation $c, n_0$ are **variables** and we want to determine $n=n(c, n_0)$ **subsequence** of $\mathbb{N}$.

So, in given case, to prove, that $n \log n \notin O(g(n))$, we need prove, that $n \log  > g(n)$ in conditions done above. Using nice idea from adjacent answer, we can consider two cases:

in case of odd $n$, for $\forall c >0, \forall n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ let's consider $n \log n > c \log n \geqslant c \log^* n$. To fulfill this inequality is enough to take $n=\max (n_0, \lfloor c \rfloor +1)$.

even case can be done in similar way.